# HtmlAgilityPack incorrect parsing of < in input

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to remove any scripts from my input using HtmlAgilityPack.

My input:

```
<div>If the amount<500 show results. Else do not show results.<mytag1>This is an xml element</mytag1></div><script>alert("welcome");</script>
```

Expected result:

```
<div>If the amount<500 show results. Else do not show results.<mytag1>This is an xml element</mytag1></div>
```

Final result:

```
<div>If the amount<500 show="" results.="" else="" do="" not="" /><mytag1>This is an xml element</mytag1></div>
```

here is my code

```
    public HashSet<string> BlackList = new HashSet<string>() 
    {
            { "script" },
            { "iframe" },
            { "form" },
            { "head" },
            { "meta" },
            { "comment" }
    };
    public static string GetSafeHtmlString(string sInputString)
    {          
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();           
        doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        //doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
        doc.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        doc.LoadHtml(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sInputString));

        HtmlSanitizer sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
        sanitizer.SanitizeHtmlNode(doc.DocumentNode);

        string output = null;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            doc.DocumentNode.WriteTo(writer);
            output = sw.ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
            {
                int at = output.IndexOf("?>");
                output = output.Substring(at + 2);
            }
            writer.Close();
        }        

        doc = null;          

        return output;
    }
    private void SanitizeHtmlNode(HtmlNode node)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            // check for blacklist items and remove
            if (BlackList.Contains(node.Name))
            {
                node.Remove();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (node.HasChildNodes)
        {
            for (int i = node.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                SanitizeHtmlNode(node.ChildNodes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I get the expected results. The html parser is taking the < as start of new html tag. How can I add "<"(less than) character that is not start of html tag in input.

Answer (score 1):

By escaping it to an HTML entity. The HTML escape sequence for `<` is `&lt;`... similarly `>` is `&gt;`.

Here's a [handy chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Comment: the input is read as InnerHtml from a text area. and when I debug I see this is what is passed to GetSafeHtmlString method &lt;div&gt;If the amount&lt;500 show results. Else do not show results.&lt;mytag1&gt;This is an xml element&lt;/mytag1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;welcome&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;. That means it is already escaped, correct?

Comment: If I use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode on the original input, the <script> is not removed from the result, which I need removed.